# How to fit my given data (cant be done by polyvar and model function is not helpful?)

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, numerical-methods

I'm trying to fit my data points to a curve - it does not matter if I use the (existing) "approximated analytical" model function or not. Obviously I tried to use it at first, but I get a Runtime error whenever I include a parameter (and it's a "heavy" function).

It's an interference pattern: [image: actual pattern]

My data looks looks like this:
[image: my data]

When I simply use the analytical function (where all parameters are known), [image: analytical function], I cannot get it right by guessing. This is how it looks like next my data [image: Plot of anal. function]

Here's the questionable code snippet (with parameter to be estimated by curve_fit):

```py
def f(x, a):
       return (((np.sin(a*np.pi*0.96*np.sin(x)*6.328*10**7))**2*(a*np.pi*0.96*np.sin(x)*6.328*10**7)**(-2))*10**11)*7**(-1)

params_, extras= curve_fit(f, x_data, y_data, maxfev=15000))
```

I then get the following error: [image: error message]

Comment: checked [this](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FittingData.html)?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's applicable in this situation given the (nested) sine**2

Comment: Your variable a will have to be a vector that encompasses I(0) and b/lambda Right now you aren’t letting the amplitude vary. I also don’t understand why you have all the 1E7, and 1e11 in there.

Comment: Wow, you have a good eye @ Jody. I normalized by dividing through I(0). The 10**x are there because of 1) the wavelength, 2) there seemed to be a dimensional error - the end result was a *10 multiple.